# Find version of Chrome browser in registry

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, registry, version

How do I get Chrome version using PowerShell? I tried the following query:

```
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome').DisplayVersion
```

This didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably what you want (it reads the version of the executable, not a value from the registry):

```
(Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo
```

Comment: This is a nice solution generally, but being a weird guy I have edited this value on my PC to point to my own launcher that runs Chrome and does some other things. What if I'm not the only one?

Comment: @wOxxOm - I would recommend against that, as it changes your system to use a non-standard configuration. (The installer puts that property there for a reason.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to get GC version and save it in a file on a server.
Hope you can use it.

```
#Set file path to store data
$filepathToStoreData = '\\v-server\Reports\O365ver\version.txt'

#Get Hostname
$hostname = Get-Content env:computername

#Get Google Chrome Version
$GCVersionInfo = (Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Window\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo
#Write-Host $GCVersionInfo.ProductVersion
$GCVersion = $GCVersionInfo.ProductVersion

#Add Date and Time
$CDate = Get-Date

$lineToWriteInFile = "$hostname,$GCVersion,$CDate"


#Writeversions in file
$lineToWriteInFile | Out-File -Encoding unicode -Append $filepathToStoreData
$lineToWriteInFile | Out-File -Encoding unicode -Append '´n'
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this location *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBeacon* now has the version value with the name *version*

Answer (score -1):

You can try following this path:

```
Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo
```

But I think it is easier to read about the Chrome version visiting the "About" Page. It is faster way in any case, visit this link for more info: https://rocketfiles.com/articles/what-version-of-chrome-do-i-have.