# How can I get Google Chrome's version number?

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, version

I am trying to get Google Chrome's version number but I can't find it.
I can see that chrome is installed:
[image]

I tried using `PowerShell`:

```
get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name, LocalPackage -AutoSize
```

but what I get is a list that doesn't contain "Google Chrome" in it.

**How can I get Google Chrome's version number?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find version of Chrome browser in registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975653/find-version-of-chrome-browser-in-registry)

Answer (score 14):

you can query the registry key.

```
(Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo
```

its fits your need?

Comment: No :( It doesn't work because that path doesn't exist. The error I get: "Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App
Paths\chrome.exe' because it does not exist."

Comment: When you run the following command, can you see google chrome? `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize`

Comment: @SaggieHaim Chrome doesn't use the uninstall regkey.

Comment: what? when i run both of the cmdlet in my PC it working great. I also use it on my company computers (more then 2K PC's with Win 10 and Win 7)

Comment: When I run the command I get an error: "Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe' because it does not exist."

Comment: `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | ? { $_ -match "Chrome" } | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize` works for me on W10.

Comment: On one test machine, I had to remove the Wow6432Node folder to find it. Probably need to check both with and without Wow6432Node::  `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | ? { $_ -match "Chrome" } | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Answer (score 5):

You can try using this (run in PowerShell 5.1):

```
$(Get-Package -Name "Google Chrome").Version
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using *Get-WmiObject*:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class CIM_DataFile -Filter "Name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'" | Select-Object Version).Version
```

Comment: Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from CIM_DataFile where Name='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\
chrome.exe'"
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-WmiObject -Class CIM_DataFile -Filter "Name='C:\\Program Files ( ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Chrome was installed to the default directory, you can use:

```
$ChromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($ChromePath).ProductVersion
```

Comment: Exception calling "GetVersionInfo" with "1" argument(s): "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
At line:2 char:1
+ [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($ChromePath).Pro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

Comment: The error indicates the file was not found. Change $ChromePath to be the location of wherever you have Chrome installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute Command on windows cmd

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" get Version /value
```

Comment: ...not from Powershell you can't

Answer (score 0):

#Get Chrome product version and send mail if is not the desired one
$ChromeDesiredVersion = "103.0.5060.134"
$ChromeVI = (Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").VersionInfo
$ChromePV = $ChromeVI.ProductVersion

#$lineToWriteInFile.ToString()
$lineToWriteInFile = "$hostname,$CDate,$ChromePV"

if( $ChromePV -lt $ChromeDesiredVersion){
Write-Host "wrong version"
$lineToWriteInFile = "$hostname,$CDate,$ChromePV"
Send-MailMessage -To "Me xxx@yourdomain.xxx" -From "ChromeCheckerChromeChecker@yourdomain.xxx" -Subject "Chrome version: $ChromePV,$hostname" -SmtpServer "smtp.yourdomain.xxx"

}else{
Write-Host "Right version"
}